# Linq to SQL query filter with Lightswitch computed property

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch, computed-properties

With the help/suggestions I received in a previous question I asked, I managed to narrow my problem down to a computed property.

Here's the query filtering that fails:

`query = query.Where(a => a.collection.Any(b => b.Name.StartsWith(c)));`

Everything in there seems to work fine but `Name` causes the query to fail. `Name` is a computed property of `b` and when I replace that by a standard property, the query works.

I do not understand what that implies in the sql so I can't figure out how to fix/replace that so I can filter by that property. If anyone could explain what's going wrong behind that query it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Your existing query will throw an exception, because without ensuring `collection` isn't null or empty, it will throw an exception anytime it encounters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties are not defined in the underlying database and so you can't reference them in your queries.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Any way to bypass that ?

Comment: Matt has hit the nail on the head. Here's a well-written article that can provide some insight on how to deal with 'computed properties' and EF: http://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework

Comment: @SRQCoder Very nice article ! Will keep on reading, looks promising.

Comment: Even though this answer is right about the direct use of computed properties, I cannot accept it yet since I'm looking for alternatives/fixes for that problem. The article in @SRQCoder 's comment is useful but not directly related to Lightswitch in particular, which has a lot of limitations. The answer is helpful though so I upvoted for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do your goal, with the following:

```
var start = "Joh";
var query = content.Where(entity => 
                  entity.ExampleCollection.Exist(obj => 
                  obj.Name.StartsWith(start));
```

That will filter based on if it `Exist` within the collection and meets your start criteria.

Comment: `Exist` isn't defined. I'm using Lightswitch oob, if that helps.

Comment: The potential issue of `null` collection you're pointing out is a real one, but it's not the issue I'm trying to fix.